# SQL: query to combine tables

Tags: sql, join

I have these MySQL Tables:

**Table A:**

```
id  t_id  type
--------------
1    1     0
2    2     0
3    3     0
4    4     0
5    5     0
6    1     1
7    2     1
8    3     1
9    4     1
10   5     1
11   1     2
12   2     2
13   3     2
14   4     2
15   5     2
```

**Table B:**

```
id  b
-------
1   ba
2   bb
3   bc
4   bd
5   be
```

**Table C:**

```
id  c
-------
1   ca
2   cb
3   cc
4   cd
5   ce
```

**Table D:**

```
id  d
-------
1   da
2   db
3   dc
4   dd
5   de
```

The type field in table A refers to another table:

```
0 -> B
1 -> C
2 -> D
```

t_id refers to the id in that specific table

Now I am looking for a query that gives me this result:

```
id    type  t_id  b     c     d
---------------------------------
1      0      1   ba    -     -
2      0      2   bb    -     -
3      0      3   bc    -     -
4      0      4   bd    -     -
5      0      5   be    -     -
6      1      1   -     ca    -
7      1      2   -     cb    -
8      1      3   -     cc    -
9      1      4   -     cd    -
10     1      5   -     ce    -
11     2      1   -     -     da
12     2      2   -     -     db
13     2      3   -     -     dc
14     2      4   -     -     dd
15     2      5   -     -     de

-  should be an empty field.
```

Is that possible in MySQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative solution is to use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.*,
        CASE WHEN a.type = 0 THEN b.b ELSE NULL END b,
        CASE WHEN a.type = 1 THEN c.c ELSE NULL END c,
        CASE WHEN a.type = 2 THEN d.d ELSE NULL END d
FROM    tableA a
        LEFT JOIN tableB b
            ON a.t_id = b.id
        LEFT JOIN tableC c
            ON a.t_id = c.id
        LEFT JOIN tableD d
            ON a.t_ID = d.id
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b53c/4)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT A.id, A.type, A.t_id, B.b, NULL AS c, NULL AS d
FROM A JOIN B ON A.t_id = b.id 
WHERE A.type = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT A.id, A.type, A.t_id, NULL, C.c, NULL
FROM A JOIN C ON A.t_id = c.id 
WHERE A.type = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT A.id, A.type, A.t_id, NULL, NULL, D.d
FROM A JOIN D ON A.t_id = d.id 
WHERE A.type = 2;
```

Comment: hey bill, your book that you have written was very definitive :D